# I can't detect text change in a search field on the actionbar

Tags: android

I have the following code, and onOptionItemSelected() never runs. it never reaches `Log.i("", "switch");`  Anyone know why?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category_menu, menu);
        Log.i("", "created menu");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("", "switch");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            Log.i("", "case 0");
            search = (EditText) item.getActionView();
            search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
            search.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
        return true;
    }

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            Log.d("", "my search logic");
        }

    };
```

Comment: There is no need to swear, use [`Log.wtf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) it stand for "what a terrible failure"...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this better. SearchView already has a listener to handle the querys.

in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu):

```
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            Log.w("SEARCH","Search: "+s);
            startSearch(s,true,null,true);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.w("SEARCH","Typing: "+s);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have any menu items in `category_menu`? `onOptionsItemSelected` gets called when an item from the menu is touched on, not just when the menu itself is opened. If you do have menu items, touch on one and then in LogCat you should see your "switch" log statement.